# allow to auto generate DBs in sql server under windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, iis, sql-server-2012, ef-code-first, connection-string

In my `web.config` I have defined following connection string for a Database that not existing in sqlexpress (code first entity framework approach)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="cityconnectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=CityPolulation;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

So once I define this on `web.config` file I can see `cityconnectionstring` listed under `Server Explorer` window `Data Conncetion` in Visual Studio.

But When I trying to Right Click on above connection string and hit `Refresh` I'm getting following error  in Visual Studio.

> Server Explorer Error
>
> server explorer unable to perform this operation see below for
>   details.
>
> Cannot open database "CityPolulation" requested by the login. The
>   login failed. Login failed for user 'PC-name\username'.

All the answers related to above error are for existing DBs.

How to set permission that can connect to sqlserver for not existing DBs under Windows Authentication.

What are the Settings I should look in `IIS` or `SQL server Management Studio`

Comment: You can't connect to a database that does not exist! If you are about to create the database, then connect to the "master" database instead

Answer (score 0):

When the connection is verified it checks that you have access to the database. If the database does not exist then you cannot verify the connection.

If as your question's title suggests, you want to create the database, then you will still need to connect to a database first. IF you have permissions to create a database then you will certainly have access to the "master" database.

However, I hope that you are not expecting all users to be able to create a database as that would mean that all of your users have far too many permissions to the server!

**EDIT** Change the connection's database to "master". That will prove that you can connect.

Then manually (in SSMS or whichever tool you use) Create the new database on the server.

Now modify your connection to use the new database connection. You should now be able to connect.

Entity Framework is not capable of creating databases. However, once you have created the database it can create tables and data.

Comment: my only concern is under windows authentication user , this defined connection string not connecting to sql server

Comment: You CAN'T connect to a sql server, you always connect to an actual database. In SSMS you are connecting to the "master" database( and "msdb") when you "connect to the server".

Comment: okay your thats comment gonna help me , once I select master as DB  , connection string connecting, but new DB not generating

Comment: How are you trying to create the database?Please add the code to the original question

Comment: using entity framework DBContext class I'm trying to generate that `CityContext : DbContext
    {
        public CityContext () : base("name=cityconnectionstring")
        {

        }`

Comment: I don't think that EF can create the database itself, but you can create the empty database then it can create everything inside. Once you have created the database manually, change the connection back to CityPopulation

Comment: Did you get there in the end? Hopefully I helped